# What is builder function in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

what is the need of highlighted function below -> Widget Function()
what is the need of builder in the end of this function ??
Can we do it build() method itself??

```
class BaseWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  **final Widget Function(
      BuildContext buildContext, SizingInformation sizingInformation) builder;**

  const BaseWidget({Key key, this.builder}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var sizingInformation = SizingInformation();
    return Container(
      child: builder(
        context,
        sizingInformation
      )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should provide the code for the builder function to know what exactly it is doing. By looking at the function's parameters I think its main goal is to determine the height and width available to the widget that will be returned from inside the builder function.

Comment: the reason mainly builder is used in flutter is because it provides the "context" so that we can access it in the child widgets. AFAIK

Comment: You could absolutely do everything in build method, without builder function.  But what happens if someone else built this BaseWidget, and you wanted to extend it adding your specific build? You would need to extend the class, override the build method and so on. What if you wanted to use similar thing in many places in your app - each with slightly different build method? You would need to extend BaseWidget class each time. With builder function approach, you don't need to do any of this. You use BaseWidget as it is - every time providing only custom builder function to do your specific work.